# route rails view in angularjs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In a rails project, I use `angularjs`. I set my `angularjs` view in `public` folder and use `ngoute` for set `url` to `template`. I have a problem with this, when I use `ngRoute`, I can just use template that exist in public folder. But I want use some `rails view` in my `templateurl` in `angularjs` controller. I have below `angularjs` controller:

`main.js.coffee`:

```
@restauranteur = angular.module('restauranteur', ['ngRoute'])

@restauranteur.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
  .when('/restaurants', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/index.html',
    controller: 'RestaurantIndexCtrl'
  })
  .when('/restaurants/:id', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/restaurants/show.html',
    controller: 'RestaurantShowCtrl'
    })
  .otherwise({
        templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
])
```

now I can just use template that exist in `public` folder.
I create `area` model by `scaffold`, I want use `app/views/areas/new.html.erb` template and `areas_controller.rb` for `localhost:3000/areas` url.

I add below code to `main.js.coffee`, but when I use this all the templates that exist in `public/templates` folder are deactive and just use rails view and when I remove below code again, project just use `angularjs` templates.

```
.when('/areas', {
        templateUrl: 'areas/new.html.erb',
        controller: areas_controller
      })
```

Where is the problem? How can I use rails controller and views in angular controller?

Comment: use the standard assets folder structure and add a new folder for angularjs templates under javascripts

Comment: If I create this folder, how can I use rails controller in angularjs code?

Comment: use for the angular js scripts names like model.js.erb and then use <%= %> for adding the right path. otherwise use 'asset/template/...' to address the files. that should work

Comment: For first guide, it's ok that I use `.erb`, but I want use second guide. My question is, Can I use rails controller that create by generator (like scaffold) in angularjs scripts without using rails tag ?!